# Animate parametric function in Colab

Tags: python, jquery-animate, google-colaboratory, curve

As COVID stay in place learning, I am online instructing my grandson on Python programming, heading toward plotting Lissajou curves.  I am using Colab, a relatively accessible option that saves notebooks to Drive folder. I am new to Python programming myself, so staying a bit ahead of my student.  The code below plots such curves. (Maybe not ideal code, but it works.) I would like to show the curve progression over time as if we were drawing the curve with a pencil.  The solutions I have tried failed for one reason or another. My grandson is in 5th grade, so I want to make the solution as simple as possible.  If there is a different Python platform that would work better for use, that info would be of interest as well.

Thanks for any clues!

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
# ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] =(9,9) 
# Data for plotting
revolutions = 2
frac = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
t = revolutions*(2*np.pi)*frac
# print(t)
delta = np.pi/2
a = 1
b = 1
w = 1.5
x = a*np.sin(w*t + delta)
y = b*np.sin(t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
# ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already done all the hardwork. Below will do what you are looking for -

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation # Module for animation

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] =(9,9) 
# Data for plotting
revolutions = 2
frac = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.001) #Added more points in array to reduce speed of animation
t = revolutions*(2*np.pi)*frac
# print(t)
delta = np.pi/2
a = 1
b = 1
w = 1.5
x = a*np.sin(w*t + delta)
y = b*np.sin(t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax.plot(x, y)
# ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.png")
#plt.show()

line, = ax.plot(x, y, color='k') #defines line color

def update(num, x, y, line):
    line.set_data(x[:num], y[:num])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x, y, line],
                              interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will give this a try tomorrow!